# Is there anyway to extend the value of a property of a parent element to a different property of a child element?

Tags: css, sass

Here's my specific situation. I need to create a 'mask' on an element. I've got a border on the element, a before pseudo element inside it which is animated, and the after pseudo element which is the same but with 0 opacity color, and a border which is the 'mask', that sits neatly within the border of the element (the effect is to cleanly cut off the animating bit before it reaches the border).

That's all fine (awkward, but fine), but the problem is that the color of the after border needs to match the background behind the element, but this could be different depending on different contexts. Is there any way to bubble up the color of the background into the color of the after border?

My solution now is to duplicate the class with the known background color variations, but that seems ugly and inefficient.

I'm using Sass, and would prefer to avoid javascript but am open to any solutions.

Comment: Can you show your code? Is more easy understand what you want with code

Comment: I'll have to recreate it in a simpler example when I have a bit of time. My code is too complex and likely to confuse the matter.

Comment: Something like this but in SASS?: [example in Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=div%20%0A%20%20background%20red%0A%20%20%26%3Aafter%20%0A%20%20%20%20border-color%20%40background)